# How to create features_train for Sklearn from two types of data

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a list of colors:

```
initialData = [u'black' u'black' u'white' u'powderblue'
 u'whitesmoke' u'black' u'cornflowerblue' u'powderblue' u'powderblue'
 u'goldenrod']
```

Each color represents a user that chose this color. And I have the labels for each color that means a gender:

```
labels_train = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

`0` means that a color is chosen by female, `1` means male. And I need to predict a gender using this knowledge and I did it like this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(initialData)
features_train = le.transform(initialData)
features_train = features_train.reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
```

But now I want to add more data to my `initialData`. What if I should predict a gender not only using color, but using bio as well? How should I change/normalize my `features_train` for this case? For example, if I have an another one list like this:

```
initialData2 = [u'Hello, my name is Bob and I love to cook' u'happy mother' ...]
```

And also labels for each element:

```
labels_train2 = [1 0]
```

**UPD**

Example of my data. It is a CSV and I use columns `link_color` and `description`:

```
_unit_id,_golden,_unit_state,_trusted_judgments,_last_judgment_at,gender,gender:confidence,profile_yn,profile_yn:confidence,created,description,fav_number,gender_gold,link_color,name,profile_yn_gold,profileimage,retweet_count,sidebar_color,text,tweet_coord,tweet_count,tweet_created,tweet_id,tweet_location,user_timezone
815719226,FALSE,finalized,3,10/26/15 23:24,male,1,yes,1,12/5/13 1:48,i sing my own rhythm.,0,,08C2C2,sheezy0,,pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/414342229096808449/fYvzqXN7_normal.png,0,FFFFFF,Robbie E Responds To Critics After Win Against Eddie Edwards In The #WorldTitleSeries t.co/NSybBmVjKZ,,110964,10/26/15 12:40,6.5873E+17,main; @Kan1shk3,Chennai
815719227,FALSE,finalized,3,10/26/15 23:30,male,1,yes,1,10/1/12 13:51,I'm the author of novels filled with family drama and romance.,68,,0084B4,DavdBurnett,,pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/539604221532700673/WW16tBbU_normal.jpeg,0,C0DEED,���It felt like they were my friends and I was living the story with them�۝ t.co/arngE0YHNO #retired #IAN1 t.co/CIzCANPQFz,,7471,10/26/15 12:40,6.5873E+17,,Eastern Time (US & Canada)
815719228,FALSE,finalized,3,10/26/15 23:33,male,0.6625,yes,1,11/28/14 11:30,louis whining and squealing and all,7696,,ABB8C2,lwtprettylaugh,,pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/657330418249658368/SBLCXdF7_normal.png,1,C0DEED,i absolutely adore when louis starts the songs it hits me hard but it feels good,,5617,10/26/15 12:40,6.5873E+17,clcncl,Belgrade
815719229,FALSE,finalized,3,10/26/15 23:10,male,1,yes,1,6/11/09 22:39,"Mobile guy.  49ers, Shazam, Google, Kleiner Perkins, Yahoo!, Sprint PCS, AirTouch, Air Force.  Stanford GSB, UVa.  Dad, Husband, Brother.  Golfer.",202,,0084B4,douggarland,,pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/259703936/IMG_8444_normal.JPG,0,C0DEED,Hi @JordanSpieth - Looking at the url - do you use @IFTTT?!  Don't typically see an advanced user on the @PGATOUR! t.co/H68ou5PE9L,,1693,10/26/15 12:40,6.5873E+17,"Palo Alto, CA",Pacific Time (US & Canada)
815719230,FALSE,finalized,3,10/27/15 1:15,female,1,yes,1,4/16/14 13:23,Ricky Wilson The Best FRONTMAN/Kaiser Chiefs The Best BAND Xxxx Thank you Kaiser Chiefs for an incredible year of gigs and memories to cherish always :) Xxxxxxx,37318,,3B94D9,WilfordGemma,,pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/564094871032446976/AOfpk-mr_normal.jpeg,0,0,Watching Neighbours on Sky+ catching up with the Neighbs!! Xxx _���_���_���_���_ُ�_�ԍ_ُ� Xxx,,31462,10/26/15 12:40,6.5873E+17,,
```

Comment: Use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment due to low reputation. I want to understand how your dataset is structured a little more in details. Let me try to put it in a table format. Does your table containing the data look something like this maybe?

```
labels_train   color             bio         

    0         'black'            something
    0         'black'            something
    0         'black'            something
    0         'black'            something
    0         'whitesmoke'       something
    1         'black'            something
    1         'cornflowerblue'   something
    1         'powderblue'       something
    1         'powderblue'       something
    1         'powderblue'       something
    1             -             'Hello, my name is Bob and I love to..
    0             -             'happy mother'
```

Comment: Hi! I know the colors and bio for all users, but yes, my data looks like your example

Comment: Mind posting more of your data? I'd like to have 5 rows of it. Are there any empty columns in the data?

Comment: There's more you should know. You can't fit classifiers on data that have characters, they should be all integers. You need more thorough understanding of what you're doing. Color is a category in this case. You need to create dummy variables for it. And bio is a string of characters. You can't fit a column containing lines of text to an ML classifier.